# Replace found string with different length?

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I'm trying to search a string followed by a character by replacing the string found by another one, BUT keeping the following character found.

I succeed to do it by using a test followed by a regexp, but I'd prefer to do it with only a regexp.

Example:

```
myVar.replace(/abc[ZER]/, x¿);
```

where `¿` is "Z", "E" or "R".

Expectation:

```
if i test abcZopu -> xZopu
if i test abcWopu -> no match
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
abc(?![^ZER])
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/43

Just replace by `whateveryouwant`

Comment: @sb22 which regex flavor does action-script use?

Comment: @vks ECMAScript 3 (revision 262), so it's basically same as javascript.

Comment: @Unihedron kk ...was just inquisitive about why he chose the simple regex vs lookahead one...but javascript does support lookaheads :)

Comment: @vks Maybe he didn't like the more efficient constructs. Then again, anyone bothering to compose the "gimme the regex" question doesn't deserve optimal code. :)

Comment: @vks your regex would be `abc(?=[ZER])`, why the need for negative lookahead and a negated character claas?

Comment: @AvinashRaj No, that is incorrect. The current regex is fine, and is placed like this so it would allow end-of-match as well.

Comment: op posted his exact input. Then why we think more than that? And also `[ZER]` in his regex ensures that there must be a character. But  vks regex matches also the exact string `abc`, think which isn't op intended.

Comment: @AvinashRaj i guess that is just an exmple.Its use would be somewhere more substantial

Answer (score 1):

Just capture the characters which are present inside the character class and replace the matched string with `x` plus the characters inside the group index 1.

```
> "abcZopu".replace(/abc([ZER])/g, 'x$1')
'xZopu'
> "abcWopu".replace(/abc([ZER])/g, 'x$1')
'abcWopu'
```

In the second example , exact input is printed as output because there  isn't any replacement occurs on that string.

Comment: Thanks, but my bad is i've forgotten to specify : not PHP, AS3.

Comment: it's not php. It's javascript.

Comment: @sb22 Then use that tag?

Comment: @sb22 did you want to replace `abc` only if it's not followed by any letter?